# Timestamp to normal date format and reverse conversion using PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp as `2011-08-27 18:29:31`. I want to convert it to `27 Aug 2011 06.29.31 PM`. Also, I want to convert this format reverse back to the previous timestamp format.
How van I do this using PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$converted = date('d M Y h.i.s A', strtotime('2011-08-27 18:29:31'));
$reversed = date('Y-m-d H.i.s', strtotime($converted));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use date()! It`s too old function. In PHP v. 5.2 and more you should use [date_format or DateTime::format object.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `date_format()` function

```
//Convert to format: 27 Aug 2011 06.29.31 PM
$converted_date = date_format('d M Y h.i.s A',strtotime($orig_date));

//Convert to format 2011-08-27 18:29:31
$converted_date = date_format('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($orig_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the date functions in PHP, especially [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) (for formatting a timestamp) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

To convert from `2011-08-27 18:29:31` to `27 Aug 2011 06.29.31 PM`:

```
echo date('d M Y, H.i.s A', strtotime('2011-08-27 18:29:31'));
```

To do the reverse:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('27 Aug 2011 06.29.31 PM'));
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to try:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d M Y, H.i.s A', '27 Aug 2011 06.29.31 PM');
echo date_format("Y-m-d H:i:s",$date);
```